# Generate reports using python that contains texts, graphics and conditional formatted pandas dataframes

Tags: python, reporting

I would like to produce some pdf (reports) that include various types of structures. These structures include texts, graphics (done in python) as well as conditionally formatted pandas dataframe. In the past I would have used R and Sweave to come up with such a solution as I'm fine with LaTeX. However, going forward I need to use Python and I'm not sure which of tools available are the best for my need. I've came across a couple of tools, like `pdfkit`, `reportLab` etc to generate reports. However, I'm not sure how well these tools go to display conditional formatting of a pandas dataframe.

So has someone experience in building such reports including conditional formatted pandas dataframes, graphics and potentially texts? Any hint / experiences would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-pdf-report-for-your-data-analysis-in-python-2bea81133b

Comment: @YScharf thanks, I've read that article, however it is not clear that my most important requirement, conditional formatted pandas dataframe, can be easily handled with it